# how to simplify / expand / apply a pattern to a function's argument

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

(I made some changes...)

very often I want to simplify the function's argument, or apply a pattern to it, eg. I want to change:

```
Exp[a(b+c)]
```

into

```
Exp[a b + a c]
```

simple pattern doesn't help:

```
Sin[a(b+c)] /. Sin[aaa_] -> Sin[Expand[aaa]]
```

gives again

```
Sin[a(b+c)]
```

However, with functions other than Simplify / Expand it seems to do what I expect:

```
Sin[a (b + c)] /. Sin[aaa_] -> Sin[f[aaa]]
```

gives

```
Sin[  f[a(b+c)]  ]
```

My usual solution was to use 2 patterns and Hold:

```
(Exp[a(b+c)] /. Exp[aaa_] -> Exp[Hold[  Expand[aaa]  ]] ) /. Hold[xxx_] -> xxx
```

which results in

```
E^(a*b + a*c)
```

The disadvantage of this method is that code gets more complicated than it's neccesary.

MY REAL LIFE EXAMPLE is:

```
ppp2 = 
 ( ppp1  
    /. { ExpIntegralEi[aaa_] -> 
           ExpIntegralEi[Hold[aaa /. { u2 -> 0, w2 -> 0, u3 -> x, w3 -> x}]], 
         Log[aaa_] -> 
           Log[Hold[aaa /. {u2 -> 0, w2 -> 0, u3 -> x, w3 -> x}]]
       }
 ) /.  Hold[xxx_] -> xxx;
```

where ppp1 is a long sum of terms containing u2, w2, u3, w3 and so on. I want to change the values of u, w2... ONLY in ExpIntegral and Log.

My other solution is a function:

```
ExpandArgument[expr_, what_] := Module[{list},
  list = Extract[expr, Position[   expr, what[_]   ]];
  list = Map[Rule[#, what[Expand[   #[[1]]   ]]] &, list];
  Return[expr /. list]
]
```

The function I wrote can be easily generalised to make it possible to use not only Expand but also Simplify and so on:

```
ApplyToArgument[expr_, ToWhat_, WhatFunction_] := Module[{list},
  list = Extract[expr, Position[   expr, ToWhat[_]   ]];
  list = Map[Rule[#, ToWhat[WhatFunction[   #[[1]]   ]]] &, list];
  Return[expr /. list]
]
```

For example:

```
ApplyToArgument[Sin[a (b + c)], Sin, Expand]
```

gives

```
Sin[a b + a c]
```

and

```
ApplyToArgument[Sin[a b + a c ], Sin, Simplify]
```

gives

```
Sin[a (b + c)]
```

This solution is easy to read but needs some refinement before being applied to many-argument functions (and I need these functions).

I guess I'm missing something fundamental about patterns in mathematica... How should I apply patterns to arguments of functions? (Or simplify, expand, etc. them)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could use `Map` (or `/@` for short) to apply a function to the arguments of another function. So for your example you could do `Expand /@ Sin[a (b + c)]` which returns `Sin[a b + a c]`. If you only want to apply the function to say the first argument, you could use `MapAt`, e.g. `MapAt[Expand, g[a (b + c), d (e + f)], 1]`

Comment: @Heike Thanks a lot for the comment. I've changed my question to explain that I dont work with single functions, but with long sums of different functions and I want to change arguments of only one type of them.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mathematica and it should be moved to mathematica.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For the first part of the question, you could consider using `RuleDelayed`:

```
Sin[a (b + c)] /. Sin[aaa_] :> Sin[Expand[aaa]]
```

gives

```
Sin[a b + a c]
```

Comment: I didn't mark this answer as an accepted one because I somehow didn't know how to do it. This answer was REALLY helpful, I use it a lot!

Answer (score 7):

Use `:>` instead of `->`. With `->`, the right hand side is immediately evaluated, and only then applied. Expansion of `aaa` of course gives just `aaa`, and therefore evaluation of `Sin[Expand[aaa]]` gives `Sin[aaa]`, thus the rule asks for replacing each application of `Sin` by itself. Then you also should not need those Hold constructs.

In a related note: Instead of applying the rule `Hold[xxx_]->xxx`, you can just pass your expression to `ReleaseHold`, for example `ReleaseHold[Hold[1+1] /. 1->2]` gives 4.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see the point. Thanks for suggesting ReleaseHold (and providing a nice example).

Answer (score 2):

Also consider using ExpandAll:

```
ExpandAll[Exp[a (b + c)]] // FullForm
```

will give:

```
Power[E, Plus[Times[a, b], Times[a, c]]]
```

(This will turn Exp[...] into E^... though)

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer (others provided that), but for these kinds of manipulations the Algebraic Manipulation Palette (Palettes -> Other) is often quite convenient:

[image]

The disadvantage is that unlike typed-in commands, this operation won't be "recorded" and saved in the notebook.